# Crop an image using multiple coordinates in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I used the "imfreehand" to crop an irregular shape and save its positions into a variable. This position variable is a 85*2 double matrix (85 points, X and Y coordinates). Now, I want to use the same position to crop another image (different layer of the image, but the location of the objects is the same). The functions I can find all requires rectangle positions (X1,X2,Y1,Y2). In my situation, I have 82 different (X,Y) coordinates, how can I use the position information to crop a new image?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to take the coordinates created by imfreehand(...) to create a cropable object on another image. You can use the function impoly(hparent,position) for this purpose.

The MathWorks page provides an example to guide you on its usage.